# Inverse of local coordinate system to latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, gis, latitude-longitude, trigonometry, inverse

I have a function to convert latitude and longitude to localCordinateSystem

```js
const EARTH_RADIUS_KM = 6371.0;

const distanceInMeters = (lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) => {
  const lonDiff = toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
  const latDiff = toRadians(lat2 - lat1);

  const a = Math.pow(Math.sin(latDiff / 2), 2) + Math.cos(toRadians(lat1)) *
    Math.cos(toRadians(lat2)) * Math.pow(Math.sin(lonDiff / 2), 2);

  const angle = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  return angle * EARTH_RADIUS_KM * 1000.0;
};

const localCoordinateSystem = (lat, lon, originLat, originLon, radius) => {
  let latDist = distanceInMeters(originLat, originLon, lat, originLon);
  let lonDist = distanceInMeters(originLat, originLon, originLat, lon);
  if (lat < originLat) latDist *= -1;
  if (lon < originLon) lonDist *= -1;

  return {
    x: parseFloat(latDist) + parseFloat(radius),
    y: parseFloat(lonDist) + parseFloat(radius),
  };
};
```

If you see the function localCoordinateSystem takes lat, lon, originLat, originLon and radius and returns x and y.

But now I want a function that takes x, y, originLat, originLon and radius and returns lat and lon.

Comment: Does this help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120679/equations-to-convert-from-global-cartesian-coordinates-to-geographic-coordinates

Comment: No it didn't...